# Mono cross platform build

Tags: build, mono, cross-platform, build-automation

Whats a good cross platform for Mono build tool. Is there some really nice that will gen build scripts for most, if not all Mono platforms. Cost may not be that important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xbuild is Mono's version of MSBuild, so that's an option.

Also, I think NAnt ensures their system works with Mono.

Comment: @jpobstm  There was a duplicate post that discussed different build options. Thanks.